# OpenCV 2.0.0 compile error in Ubuntu

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to install OpenCV 2.0.0 on Ubuntu 12.4 LTS and getting compile error as below

/home/mr/Downloads/OpenCV-2.0.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:356:15: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘delta1’
/home/mr/Downloads/OpenCV-2.0.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:358:9: error: ‘delta1’ was not declared in this scope
/home/mr/Downloads/OpenCV-2.0.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:367:31: error: ‘delta2’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]:  [src/cxcore/CMakeFiles/cxcore.dir/cximage.o] Error 1
make[1]:  [src/cxcore/CMakeFiles/cxcore.dir/all] Error 2
make:  [all] Error 2

Comment: "I am trying to install OpenCV 2.0.0" - don't. that's 4 years old .. instead, [try with 2.4.8](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.8/opencv-2.4.8.zip/download)

Comment: So what if old version..Is there any compatibility problem

Comment: again, that's a known bug that got fixed in a later version. (like a couple of others you will run into) ..  do the world a favour and try *not* to live under a rock

Comment: I am extending matlab project of my senior and he told me that i should use OpenCV 2.0.0 so i tried it.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV version you use is too old. Try using the latest version.

There are serious compatibility issues for old OpenCV version in latest Ubuntu releases.

If you really want to get v2.0.0 compiled, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/396439/64408) might help you out.